# SwiftUI Color doesn't update on main page

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5, uicolor, userdefaults

All my text in my app use the color `Color.textColor` which changes due to a UserDefault setting:

```
extension Color {
    public static var textColor: Color {
        let color = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "redText") ? Color.red : Color.white
        return color
    }
}
```

This is changed via a toggle in my settings section. The problem is, when I toggle this it successfully changes all text colours all my views, apart from the main view.

I've made a gif here to showcase the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2nKr.jpg 
The bug is there in both simulation and preview.

Edit: When I switch off/on the preview the main page colours actually update to the correct colour.

Comment: Show the code for the switch

Comment: View is just not refreshed, because has not observable dependency on textColor. Use either AppStorage (for SwiftUI 2.0) or onReceive with defaults notification publisher. Also it is possible to make this textColor published property of some view model and observe it.

Comment: @Asperi AppStorage worked, thanks.